# Zappa Update failing in CircleCI

Tags: python, circleci, zappa

I am trying to deploy my Python project to AWS Lambda using Zappa and circleci.

its throwing error `Error: Zappa requires an active virtual environment!`

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
zappa update dev
(PyYAML 3.13 (/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('PyYAML>=4.1'), {'cfn-flip'})
Calling update for stage dev..
Error: Zappa requires an active virtual environment!
Learn more about virtual environments here: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/
Exited with code 1
```

I am installing venv using the below commands.

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

Is there something that I am missing. 
Could someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do install zappa , virtualenv using pip3 and then activate it.

```
sudo pip install zappa
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv -p python3 venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
zappa update dev
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a short working example that uses python3 virtual env, not virtualenv package.
For it to work you need to set `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` as env vars in the CircleCI web UI.

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.6.1

    working_directory: ~/app

    steps:
      - checkout

      - run:
          name: install dependencies
          command: |
            python3 -m venv ~/venv
            . ~/venv/bin/activate
            pip install -r requirements.txt

      - deploy:
          name: deploy
          command: |
            . ~/venv/bin/activate

            # set aws credentials
            mkdir -p ~/.aws
            echo -e "[default]" >> ~/.aws/credentials
            echo -e "aws_access_key_id = "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID >> ~/.aws/credentials
            echo -e "aws_secret_access_key = "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY >> ~/.aws/credentialstrouble

            # try to update, if the command fails do the initial deploy
            zappa update dev || zappa deploy dev;
```

Note that I'm using python 3.6.1 CircleCI image, I had some minor trouble with 3.6.9

Full example with dependencies caching, running test suite, testing if the package can be created, deployment to *testing* and *production* environment can be found here: https://github.com/mislavcimpersak/xkcd-excuse-generator/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml